# red5phone sound problem

Tags: red5, sip

I have installed Red5 Server 0.9.0 and red5phone sip_r53. When i make a call , am not able to hear caller voice but he can hear me clearly. can any one faced similar problem ? please help.

Thanks and Regards,
Seniel

Comment: i had the same issue. how did you fix it?  I checked speaker levels it is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be many things! Need more info. From my experience the most likely reasons are fire-walled ports (check iptables rules, make sure you can send udp data to some random ports from remote machine to your host using netcat or something), then goes NAT. Are you behind NAT? If so, is your client NAT-aware, does it require STUN server, etc ? 
Also it might be a good idea to check the speaker level on your machine and mic on the remote =)

Answer (score 0):

When I search with keyword "Red5Phone" in Stackoverflow, and just 10 question appeared. :) I think our problems are same.
Hi, sunil. A moment ago, I successfully made a call using red5phone. I was using latest red5phone version from subversion, Red5 0.8.0, and Asterisk win32. I hope you also can make it.
Maybe like tuxxxedo says, it's about your Asterisk configuration.
don't forget put this in your extensions.conf

```
exten => 55,1,Playback(demo-echotest) ; Let them know what’s going on
exten => 55,2,Echo ; Do the echo test
exten => 55,3,Playback(demo-echodone) ; Let them know it’s over
```

try it.

Answer (score 0):

I also experiencing this.  I tried on Red5 0.9.1 and Chrome browser.  I could not hear the voice both way even though dialer end up dialing.  When i tried with firefox 5.0 and flash player 10 it worked on from red5phone remote phone but did does not work the other way. If the remote machine does to allow incomming udp as above reader suggest how do we fix this?